# What command VS executes when rebuilding a project

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, msbuild, code-analysis

I am having some problem with my project. When I build project using Visual Studio (Right Click -> Build/Rebuild) then output window shows no code analysis warnings. And even if I run code analysis manually on project it doesn't show any warnings,

But when I try to build the same project using this command through VS Commandline, I receive code analysis warnings.

msbuild /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="AnyCPU" /p:BuildProjectReferences=false MyCSharpProject.csproj

I want to know what command VS runs (I think it builds using csc.exe) but what is the actual command.

Comment: what VS does internally is convert the solution file to an msbuild file and then build that. I think there's an option to make it keep the converted file but I can't find it atm. Anyway if you run your builds with high verbosity that might give a clue (Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSbuild verbosity)

Comment: @stijn, set the msbuildemitsolution environment variable to "1", then you'll see a .metaproj and .metaproj.tmp project files in the same folder as the solution.